# File Path in WordPress not as default

Tags: wordpress, image, path

I have an issue with wordpress image file paths.

Have no idea how this happened but all images are blank on media gallery, and after a lot of trying different things to fix have realised that the image filepath is showing

https:///wp-content/

as opposed to

https://example.com/wp-content/

Have tried search and replace which I thought would fix, but hasnt worked...any ideas much appreciated!!!

Comment: Do you see all images in admin panel on media tab section??

Comment: I see the box but it is blank....i have also tried regenerate thumbnails

Comment: So i see all image boxes but they are all blank

Comment: but the image files exist in the directory?

Comment: Yes...for example if I use firebug inspector and then just edit the image code with the proper URL i.e https://example.com/wp-content - the image displays

Comment: Are you using any plugin or theme to display images, optimize images or gallery etc? 
my second thought is, you have messed with baseURL of website.

Comment: I have deactivated all plugins, removed any caching plugins, reset permalinks etc etc. Yes I think you are right too but cannot see how to resolve??

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild) to the get all images in Media Gallery tab.

Thanks!!

Comment: No this didnt work either but thanks....this is more a corrupt file path which needs resetting somehow in my opinion

Comment: Then you have to upload the images manually in admin panel as "Media Gallery" Tab

Comment: No this is the point - the path is now corrupted somehow so even for new images the problem is the same just blank - and bear in mind there are also 500+ images anyway so need to get to the root cause of the issue

Comment: Try to Increasing Your WordPress Memory Limit in wp-config.php like define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M'); and again try to upload the new image

Comment: I have done that as well to about 800mb!!! I think I need someone to explain how to reset the file path...all these more simple things I have done